# Set order item permalink from the parent variable product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

On the thank you page and in order emails, the permalink for variable products always links directly to the product variation instead of the parent product itself, e.g., https://mystore.com/some-product/?attribute_color=red. I need the permalink to reflect the product and not the variation, e.g. https://mystore.com/some-product/.

I've tried the following:

```
$parent_id = $product->get_parent_id();
$slug = $product->get_permalink($parent_id);
```

The variable

```
$parent_id
```

returns correctly, but

```
$slug
```

is always the variation permalink. What am I missing? Alternatively, I've tried to retrieve the post name of the parent like so

```
$parent_id = $product->get_parent_id();
$slug = $product->get_post_name($parent_id);
```

but this throws an error and the thank you page only partially renders.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override any template file, just use the following hooked function, to replace the product variation permalink, by the parent variable product permalink on all orders:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_permalink', 'filter_order_item_permalink_callback', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_item_permalink_callback( $product_permalink, $item, $order ) {

    // For product variations
    if( $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ){
        $product    = $item->get_product();
        $is_visible = $product && $product->is_visible();

        // Get the instance of the parent variable product Object
        $parent_product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );

        // Return the parent product permalink (if product is visible)
        return $is_visible ? $parent_product->get_permalink() : '';
    }
    return $product_permalink;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

---

**For email notifications**

WooCommerce doesn't display, by default, the product permalink in the email notifications…

To display the product permalink on email notifications, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'filter_order_item_name_callback', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_item_name_callback( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {

    // On emails notifications only
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() > 0 ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // For product variation type
        if( $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ){

            // Get the instance of the parent variable product Object
            $parent_product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );

            // The parent product permalink (if product is visible)
            $product_permalink = $parent_product->get_permalink();
        } 
        // For other item (product) type
        else {
            $product_permalink = $product->get_permalink();
        }

        return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', $product_permalink, $item_name );
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: This works in order-details-item.php. In the order email however $product_permalink does not return a value. I am trying to echo a custom link like so: 

echo '<a href="'> . $product_permalink . '?pdf=some-value"'>'

where $product_permalink is always the parent value.

Comment: This broke my site when I put it in functions.php. I added 

`if( $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ){
$parent_product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );
$product_permalink = $parent_product->get_permalink();
} 
else {
$product_permalink = $product->get_permalink();
}`

to email-order-items.php and am now able to get the parent permalink to return correctly for variations, but it is an actual link- I need it as a string only so that I can customize the final link, e.g.

`echo '<a href="' . $product_permalink . '?pdf=some-value">Link text here</a>' ;`

Comment: The issue is that I need the parent permalink returned as as string because I am generating a custom link to include in the confirmation email:

`echo '<a href="' . $product_permalink . '?pdf=some-value">Link text here</a>' ;`
Your solution works to change the link itself when the item name is output in the order email, but I need more control.